# Can CORS be selectively disabled for the empty browser tab?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, javascript

I'd like to play with the JavaScript fetch API, fetching various urls, etc. so I opened an empty browser tab, popped up the console, typed the JavaScript, but the request failed because of CORS.

I know CORS is there for a reason, so I want that when browsing websites, I don't want to disable it completely, but I'd like to have it disabled when I open a new tab in my browser which is an empty page, so there is no security issue.

How can I configure Chrome and/or Firefox to do that?